# Git branch that tracks snapshots of master

Tags: git

I would like to maintain a parallel branch to master that periodically snapshots the master branch. The first snapshot on the branch can be accomplished using `git merge --squash`, but I'm not sure how best to capture the next snapshot.

The working copies of E and F are equivalent. I'm trying to figure out the best way to create J such that it's working copy is equivalent to I, but it's parent is F.

```
A-B-C-D-E---G-H-I
\_________F_______J
```

I have discovered that while at F `git diff --binary I | git apply --reverse` does what I want, but I don't know if this is the optimal way.

I'm looking for the git way of having two clones checked out at F and I and just wholesale copying I onto F to create J.

Comment: What is your motivation for doing this?  I think this kind of thing would typically be accomplished with [tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging).

Comment: Tags still contain the development history. We want to create a clean branch to be able to  handoff to the client periodically while not stifling the developers from committing often during development.

Comment: @matt Cherry pick could work, assuming you know _exactly_ which commits to apply, but tracking that is not so easy.

Comment: What do you mean by "handoff"? Why is it a problem for the client to see the development history? Wouldn't they still have repository access?

Comment: "handoff" - transfer of information between two parties
Developers can be quite cavalier in their development comments, most will disappear when the feature/bugfix branches get squashed onto master, but there still could be embarrassing content in the commits.
Deploying to an clean branch can then be pushed to an outward facing repo's master for client handoff.

Everyone, remember you're supposed to be constructive in this forum, not question why, the fact is that its desirable and needed for my situation so stick to trying to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out a complete way that accounts for deleted files as well as not messing up submodules.

```
git checkout <dest e.g. F>
git ls-files | xargs rm
rm -rf *
git checkout <src e.g. I> -- .
git add .
git commit
```

Comment: `rm -rf *`? Isn't it better to do `git rm -rf *` so that git deletes _tracked_ content only itself?

Comment: Additionally, `git -C <REPO_ROOT_DIR> <COMMAND> <ARGS...>` and `git add --all`